# Netplan ignores try and apply arguments

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vps, netplan

When I enter command like:
`netplan try`
or
`netplan apply`
netplan outputs nothing.
If I try again to start those commands netplan outputs error:

```
bind: address already in use
netplan: fatal error: cannot bind to port 2983, is another daemon running?, exiting.
```

So the netplan runs some process as if I started the service.

netplan config file:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    {network dev}:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [{some one public IP}]
      gateway4: {XXX.XXX.XXX}.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8]
```